# How to update multiple rows sharing same foreign key in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 tables; `db_file_acess and db_file_access_details`. I have a column `subjects_id` in `db_file_access_details` table. From the UI, I can select several subjects[array] with other details and insert them to `db_file_acess` table, and subject_ids to the `db_file_access_details`. Insertion is OK but when I update the two tables, I can't seem to update all the rows. This is my update query

```
$result = array();
        foreach ($subject_id as $key => $val) {
            $result[] = array(
                'file_access_id' =>$q_id,
                'subjects_id' => $_POST['subject_id'][$key]
            );
        }
        $this->db->update_batch('db_file_access_details', $result, 'file_access_id');
```

The query runs but it updates with only one id as seen in the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot]

the `result()` array is as shared below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_access_id] => 45
            [subjects_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_access_id] => 45
            [subjects_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file_access_id] => 45
            [subjects_id] => 4
        )

)
```

after update_batch query, the resultant results is as shown below
[image: screenshot]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs `update_batch('db_file_access_details', $result, 'file_access_id')` produces:

```
UPDATE `db_file_access_details` SET `subjects_id` = CASE
WHEN `file_access_id` = 45 THEN 1
WHEN `file_access_id` = 45 THEN 3
WHEN `file_access_id` = 45 THEN 4
ELSE `subjects_id` END
WHERE `file_access_id` IN (45, 45, 45)
```

For all three rows, the first case matches, so all `subject_id`s are set to 1.

For update_batch to work correctly you need to use the `id` column.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could also consider deleting all rows for the `file_access_id` in `db_file_access_details` and then inserting the `$result` array with insert_batch instead.

Comment: A great solution. Had not thought of this. Solved my problem by deleting all rows then re-insert data again as a batch, thanks @Marleen